# Mobile form on website is not sending on the first click of "submit"

Tags: iphone, forms, mobile, dotnetnuke

this is kind of a weird issue I'm having with a site's form when viewed on an iPhone5. When somebody fills in the information and tries hitting submit, it refreshes the page with all of the content still on the page but none of the tasks triggering. No errors or warnings are shown. When the user clicks submit again, the form works as intended.. so the first click doesn't seem to be working.

I don't own an iPhone5, but I tried this on both Safari and on my DROID4 (which both worked fine).

The site is built with DotNetNuke version 6, ASP.net, the forms are a module called DynamicForms, though I don't know if that information is needed.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to get in touch with the good folks at Data Springs, the creators of the Dynamic Forms module.  They provide really good support.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what triggers you have, but that sounds like the browser for the device isn't actually doing the event.  As for a potential work around, in your skin but [this](http://jsfiddle.net/K8ngn/):

```
$(function () {
     $(".SubmitButtonAnchor").click(function () {
           if(window.confirm(location.href)) {
                window.location = "http://bing.com";
           }
     });
});
```

The above example should anchor to your input button and do the following:

- When you *Submit* it will prompt you of the page it is attempting to navigate to.
- The ability to say "Yes" or "No".
- Then navigate to the page.

This should bypass some issues you may be experiencing currently, I'd still let them know that it isn't working as intended.